# Why does free() cause an error in my code when it's there, but everything runs well when it is not there?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

My program takes an arbitrary number of words at runtime and stores them in a dynamically-sized array of words.

Currently, my program runs well, except when I use `free()` to free up the memory of the temporary double pointer `temp`. I am not quite sure why it does this, as I thought it would cause errors if I didn't use it.

```
int wordSize = 10, arrSize = 1, i = 0;
char **stringArr, **temp;
char *input;

stringArr = malloc(arrSize * sizeof(char *));

puts("Accepting input...");

for (;;) {
    if (i >= arrSize) {
        arrSize += 1;
        temp = realloc(stringArr, arrSize * sizeof(char *));

        if (temp != NULL) {
            stringArr = temp;
            free(temp); // This is the line that is giving me issues; removing it works
        } else {
            puts("Could not allocate more memory");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    stringArr[i] = malloc(sizeof(input));
    input = malloc(wordSize * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%10s", input);

    if (strcmp(input, "END")) {
        strcpy(stringArr[i], input);
        i++;
    } else
        break;
       
}
free(stringArr);
```

At the bottom of my program I use `free()` without any issues. How come it works OK here but not earlier on in the program.

I feel I am missing something about how `free()` works.

Note: this is my first program implementing `malloc()` and `realloc()`, so I am only just getting used to how they work. If you know of a better way to accomplish what I am doing that, please feel free to describe.

Comment: Try running with valgrind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `free(temp);` line is causing an error (later on) because, in the preceding line, `stringArr = temp;`, you are assigning the *address* that is stored in the `temp` pointer to that in the `stringArr` pointer. Thus, when you free the memory pointed to by `temp` you also free the memory pointed to by `stringArr`, because it is the **same** memory block. Copying a pointer's value from one variable to another **does not** make a (separate) copy of the memory.

Omitting the `free(temp);` line is correct, because that memory is freed later on, in the `free(stringArr);` call.

Comment: Ah, yes! I often make the mistake of forgetting that pointers work like this. Thanks a lot, Adrian :)

Answer (score 1):

You must not free the reallocated array when reallocation was successful. If you do that, the code will modify this freed block, which has undefined behavior and you will have further undefined behavior when you later try and reallocate or free this block.

Note also the following:

- pre-allocating `stringArr` with a size of `1` is not necessary. Just initialize `stringArr` to `0` and `arrSize` to `0`. `realloc()` can take a null pointer and will behave like `malloc()`.
- `stringArr[i] = malloc(sizeof(input));` is incorrect: it will allocate a `char` array with a size of 4 or 8 depending on the size of a pointer on the target architecture, not `11` bytes as it should.
- if the `wordSize` is the maximum length of a word, you should allocate one more byte for the null terminator. The `10` in `%10s` must match the value of `wordSize`, which is cumbersome because there is no easy way to pass this to `scanf()` as a variable.
- you do not check the return value of `scanf()`, causing undefined behavior in case of premature end of file.
- you have memory leaks: `input` is allocated for each iteration but never freed, freeing `stringArr` without freeing the strings pointed to by its elements makes them inaccessible.

It would be more efficient to use a local array to try and read the words with `scanf()` and only allocate the string and reallocate the array if successful.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int arrSize = 0;
    char **stringArr = NULL;
    char input[11];
    
    puts("Accepting input...");
    
    while (scanf("%10s", input) == 1 && strcmp(input, "END") != 0) {
        char **temp = realloc(stringArr, (arrSize + 1) * sizeof(*stringArr));
        if (temp != NULL) {
            stringArr = temp;
        } else {
            puts("Could not allocate more memory");
            break;
        }
        stringArr[arrSize] = strdup(input);
        if (stringArr[arrSize] == NULL) {
            puts("Could not allocate more memory");
            break;
        }
        arrSize++;
    }
    puts("Array contents:");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        printf("%i: %s\n", i, stringArr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        free(stringArr[i]);
    }
    free(stringArr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, man. I appreciate the info :)